# Replacing NameSpaces one from Another using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have one XML input file in which I am getting some Namespaces which I wanted to replace from another using XSLT. Actually I am new XSLT so not able to find proper solution. below is the XML input payload and Output payload which I want. Could anyone help me on that.

Input Payload:

```
<ns:createOrderResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com"><ns:return type="com.ecc.ecom.oms.beans.xsd.CreateOrderResponse"><ns:omsGeneratedOrderId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" /><ns:responseCode>99</ns:responseCode><ns:responseDesc>INVALID ORDER</ns:responseDesc><ns:sellerSiteId>10196</ns:sellerSiteId><ns:serverProcElapsedTime>8</ns:serverProcElapsedTime><ns:siteGeneratedOrderId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" /><ns:subResponse><responseCode xmlns="http://beans.oms.ecom.ecc.com/xsd">1144</responseCode><responseDescription xmlns="http://beans.oms.ecom.ecc.com/xsd">Order Total mismatch</responseDescription></ns:subResponse><ns:subResponse><responseCode xmlns="http://beans.oms.ecom.ecc.com/xsd">1147</responseCode><responseDescription xmlns="http://beans.oms.ecom.ecc.com/xsd">Order Grand Total and sum of OrderItem Grand Total mismatch</responseDescription></ns:subResponse><ns:transactionNumber>0717299145</ns:transactionNumber></ns:return></ns:createOrderResponse>
```

---

Desired Output:

```
<ns:createOrderResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com"><ns:return type="com.ecc.ecom.oms.beans.xsd.CreateOrderResponse"><ns:omsGeneratedOrderId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" /><ns:responseCode>99</ns:responseCode><ns:responseDesc>INVALID ORDER</ns:responseDesc><ns:sellerSiteId>10196</ns:sellerSiteId><ns:serverProcElapsedTime>8</ns:serverProcElapsedTime><ns:siteGeneratedOrderId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" /><ns:subResponse><responseCode xmlns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">1144</responseCode><responseDescription xmlns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">Order Total mismatch</responseDescription></ns:subResponse><ns:subResponse><responseCode xmlns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">1147</responseCode><responseDescription xmlns="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">Order Grand Total and sum of OrderItem Grand Total mismatch</responseDescription></ns:subResponse><ns:transactionNumber>0717299145</ns:transactionNumber></ns:return></ns:createOrderResponse>
```

Basically I wanted to replace:

Namespace :http://beans.oms.ecom.shc.com/xsd
from 
Namespace :http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT: The following is untested but demonstrates the ideas.

If you know which specific elements and attributes to expect, that's relatively easy -- it's the same as any other "when you see this element, output this other element instead" template, recursing to cover the whole document. Start with the identity stylesheet and add appropriate templates of the form:

```
<xsl:template match="wrongnamespace:fred"
      xmlns:wrongnamespace="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">
  <rightnamespace:fred xmlns:rightnamespace="http://beans.oms.ecom.shc.com/xsd">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </rightnamespace:fred>
</xsl:template>
```

and (for attributes)

```
<xsl:template match="@wrongnamespace:george"
      xmlns:wrongnamespace="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com">
   <xsl:attribute name="ns:george" value="."
          namespace="http://beans.oms.ecom.shc.com/xsd"/>
</xsl:template>
```

... and so on.

If you don't know what elements or attributes to expect, this becomes uglier. In XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 there's no easy way to say "any element node" (though I believe that was fixed in the 2.0 version of these specs). Sticking with 1.0 because it's more widely supported, the easiest solution is to use priorities: have a higher-priority template that catches the attributes, then have another template which handles other namespaced nodes (which would therefore be elements).

```
<xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri(.)="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com"
        priority="1">
    <xsl:attribute name="concat('ns:',localname(.))" value="."
            namespace="http://beans.oms.ecom.shc.com/xsd"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[namespace-uri(.)="http://services.oms.ecom.ecc.com"
           priority="1">
       <xsl:element name="concat('ns:',localname(.))"
              namespace="http://beans.oms.ecom.shc.com/xsd">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Again, adding these to the canonical identity stylesheet will do what you need; it'll catch and change these two cases while copying everything else unaltered.

CAVEAT: THIS WILL NOT CHANGE URIS APPEARING IN STRINGS. You could add a template which looks for text() nodes containing the old URI and outputs the new one instead; I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader.

CAVEAT: THIS WILL NOT CHANGE NAMESPACE NODES. You may wind up with leftover declarations of the old prefix and namespace. Another template could be added to clean that up; this too is left as an exercise for the reader.

That should give you enough to get you started. Have fun. Programming in XSLT does require learning to think in terms of rules and replacements rather than procedures, but when you get used to that it can be a very expressive tool.

(Standard plug: If you want an off-the-shelf tested solution, you can probably find one on Dave Pawson's XSL FAQ website. That's a resource you really need to be aware of if working in XSLT; it'll save you a lot of work, and it has some solutions that are very clever and very non-obvious.)